# How to use Monaco-Editor in VSCode Extension

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I am writing a CustomTextEditor-Extension for Visual Studio Code.

I‘d like to have the overview on the right, and the line-count on the left - the typical Monaco Editor features.

The editor itself should just be an enhanced monaco editor. Right now I have to make it myself, from scratch.

How can I unwrap or include the Monaco Editor, to use it in my CustomTextEditor Extension?

Comment: Why do you want to use an own monaco-editor instance? You can just open a new text editor instance in vscode and have a full monaco-editor with all additions from vscode at hand.

Comment: @MikeLischke Because I want to make a Custom Editor for Markdown files. Which scans a second file (set by command) and then highlights and manipulates lines in the file i'm currently writing in, based on stuff in the second file. I found no other way for doing this, than making a custom editor.
If you know a better way, let me know.